# Exclude non-minified files from publish with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, webdeploy

Currently I'm using this publish profile (.pubxml) for publication:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>17e8801d-27bf-4b5a-a0f5-125b0e52dde9</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <publishUrl>C:\000\Test</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <EnvironmentName>Production</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MaxifiedJs Include="wwwroot/**/*.js" Exclude="wwwroot/**/*.min.js" />
    <MaxifiedCss Include="wwwroot/**/*.css" Exclude="wwwroot/**/*.min.css" />
    <Content Update="@(MaxifiedJs)" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
    <Content Update="@(MaxifiedCss)" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It's working good and removes all non-minified files from output folder. But the problem appears when file haven't minified version. In this case nothing published. How to make this rules works ONLY when file has minified version? If there is no minified file, then publish regular .js or .css
I didn't found any solution in official documentation or StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

> Exclude non-minified files from publish with ASP.NET Core 3.1

As far as I know, that is not possible to retain a single js or css(without minified files) file when publishing.

To determine two similar files, you need to capture the same part for comparison, but the capture in msbuild is only for properties. Properties can only be overridden by previous values.

**Suggestion**

To achieve this, you should use your function and then copy the single js into Publish folder manually.

Or just copy all files and then delete the non-minified files.

Answer (score 0):

name your existing non-minified files say script.debug.js  if you have a script.js or script.min.js these will copy just exclude

```
     wwwroot/**/*.debug.*
```